# How to save data from firebase on variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, leaflet

I was tried to save coordinate from the firebase database to the variable but when I use it, it says "Undefined variable". So I want to know how to store it on a variable (I'm a newbie in javascript)

Here is HTML file code
``` 


Leaflet example

```
    <!-- include leaflet css and javascript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin=""
            href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"
                    crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="leaflet-polycolor.min.js"></script>


    <!-- include our own css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-example.css" />

    <!-- we include the javascript at the bottom, see below -->



</head>

<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-functions.js"></script>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- include our own javascript -->
    <script src="leaflet-example.js"></script>



</body>
```

```
And Here is Js file 
    ```        
         var leafletPolycolor = require('leaflet-polycolor');
         leafletPolycolor.default(L);

```
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
     var firebaseConfig = {
           // Actually have a config but I have to keep it
       };
      // Initialize Firebase
     firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref("/coordinates/");
    var sto;
    var functions = firebase.functions;
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [45.1834782, 5.7831946],
        zoom: 20
     });
    ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   
    sto=snapshot.val();

     }, function(error) {
    
     console.error(error);
     });
     console.log(sto);
     L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}"", {foo: 
     "bar"}).addTo(map);


      var latLngs = [[45.187273, 5.758124], [45.182772, 5.758516], [45.185767, 5.747106], 
      [45.176569, 5.752082], [45.171863, 5.757120], [45.168354, 5.755178]];
      var colors = ["red", "red", "red", "green", "yellow", "yellow"];

      var polyline = L.polycolor(sto,{ colors: colors,weight: 5 }).addTo(map);
```

```
And this is my database
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pSae.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your logic to be inside the callback as it's asynchronous and probably didn't finish by the time you're trying to log it:

```js
ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    const sto = snapshot.val();
    console.log(sto);
  }, function(error) {
       console.error(error);
});
```